# HDFS' ZKFC service unable to start

Tags: high-availability, failover, hadoop, zookeeper, cloudera

`CDH4's ZooKeeper Failover Controller (ZKFC)` has been installed.

Starting the ZKFC service:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo service hadoop-hdfs-zkfc start                      
Starting Hadoop zkfc:                                      [  OK  ]
starting zkfc, logging to /var/log/hadoop-hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-zkfc-localhost.localdomain.out
```

does not seem to work as the log file is empty:

`sudo vim  /var/log/hadoop-hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-zkfc-localhost.localdomain.log`

**Question**

How to run HDFS' ZKFC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just installing the ZKFC and starting it is not sufficient. HDFS' NameNode (NN) needs to be installed, High Availability (HA) needs to be enabled for this NN to avoid `HA is not enabled for this namenode.` error and to avoid `Missing required configuration 'ha.zookeeper.quorum' for ZooKeeper quorum` issue `ha.zookeeper.quorum` needs to be configured in HDFS' core-site.xml

/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml

```
 <property>
   <name>ha.zookeeper.quorum</name>
   <value>ip1:2181,ip2:2181,ip3:2181</value>
 </property>
```

Cloudera documents this extensively in their [High Availability Guide](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/latest/CDH4-High-Availability-Guide/cdh4hag_topic_2.html).

Comment: In addition, you also need to run the "hdfs zkfc –formatZK" so the right znodes are set up in zookeeper.